# for-loops vs x.Times(...) extension methods

Tags: functional-programming

Using C# as an example, extensions on `IEnumerable` to allow code like `collection.Each(i => i.DoStuff)` rather than a `foreach` loop are generally frowned upon, mainly because they don't follow LINQ conventions of being functional, in that the functions they take are statements rather than expressions, written to have side-effects.

Does the same thing apply to an extension to allow code like...

```
10.times(() => ThingIWantToDo10Times())
```

On one hand it's still clearly not functional, but on the other, it's not an extension on `IEnumerable`.

Would an extension like this be frowned upon for the same reasons?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that your second code example is verbose and thus hides one of the key benefits to your extension method. It can be expressed as:

```
10.times(ThingIWantToDo10Times);
```

(though make that `Times`, please. C# methods are PascalCase, not camelCase.)

The terseness of such an expression is a big plus point. But, you are right, many folk do not like it as it's using a functional pattern to create side-effects. [It's worth reading this post by Eric Lippert, as it goes into a lot of detail on why that can be seen as wrong](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

If though, after reading that, you still prefer the idea of using an extension method, then do so. It's all just opinion after all...

Comment: Tenseness of such an expression is a slight negative. Give me a plain old loop any day. Easier to read, way easier to maintain and debug. The obsessive focus on brevity is in part why functional languages remain on the fringes.

Comment: @Telastyn: The real problem here is the side-effects in a functional context, not brevity necessarily.  Also, what is a fluent interface actually doing under the covers?  Hard to tell without looking at the underlying source code.

Comment: @Telastyn, sure some folk dislike declarative code and want to see what's really going on. Assembler is a good choice for those folk.

Comment: I've read that Eric Lippert article a number of times, and totally agree with it, but it's concentrating on sequence operators. This extension isn't on sequence, and has clear side-effecting semantics, which is why I wonder if the concerns about the non-functional-ness of it still apply.

Comment: Higher order functions can be useful without having to go 100% pure functional programming. OP has provided a nice example, especially considering that the host language is C# which is very non-pure-functional. By the same reasoning we would not be allowed to use callbacks with side effects! Instead, there's a much simpler argument against this extension method: it's unidiomatic in C# (but compare e.g. Smalltalk or Ruby where such methods are be idiomatic).